# Would objectivist utilitarianism be considered to be a form of moral absolutism?

Tags: terminology, utilitarianism, metaethics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_absolutism) defines **moral absolutism** as the view that "there is at least one principle that ought never to be violated". Does this mean that even someone who holds morally objectivist utilitarianism would be considered a moral absolutist, as they believe it's a fact not maximizing the amount of good one can do is one principle which should never be violated?

Comment: No. The "principle" in moral absolutism must judge the morality of action on its features *at the time of acting* (even Wikipedia opens with "moral absolutism is an ethical view that some (potentially all) actions are *intrinsically* right or wrong"). Since utilitarianism, and consequentialism generally, make morality of action dependent on its consequences they are automatically disqualified.